# Regex/grep/findstr for locating memory allocation C++

Tags: c++, regex, memory-management

I have quite a few source files in nested subfolders for a project. I have 4 different classes that I am attempting to replace, and want to locate every place in the source they are allocated (heap + stack).

Unfortunately, due to a poor include structure, Visual Studio's "search entire solution" feature cannot be trusted, so I have resorted to a manual search within the source files.

What I believe is sufficient:

`"new CLASS1("` with any combination of spaces between the three tokens there for heap and
`"^CLASS2"`     where I'm trying to say the Class name starts at the beginning of the line (excluding spaces) for stack allocation.

For stack allocation, `[^a-zA-Z] CLASS3 [a-zA-Z]+` was attempted, but I'm not fluent in regex so wanted to run this by SO. For heap, just that string above was tried, but I know that a simple extra spacing would break that pattern so I know it is incorrect.

Can anyone come up with a better matcher ***or even an entirely better way to go about the problem?***

Thank you,

AK

Comment: That third one makes no sense, and all of them fail in the presence of templates or typedefs.  My solution would be to rename all of the classes, and the compiler errors will show you where it's used.

Comment: @MooingDuck yeah, not sure why it's not just space characters before CLASS3, but wanted to make sure i wasn't second guessing arbitrarily. There are no templates or typedefs declared for these classes, nor are there any inheritance type issues. I did indeed think about renaming the classes, but these are quite critical and are used EVERYWHERE. wouldn't almost every line break (even non-allocation lines? - class,struct,union expected before ->, etc?)

Comment: yes, but if you're replacing them, then the _first_ error will always be a piece of code you have to change. (Also you'll probably want to find members, but your "stack allocation" regexes will probably pick that up)

Comment: @MooingDuck ah, yeah that'd be perfect if i had made my situation more clear - I actually have to manually deal with the allocation of the replacement classes, so needed to first see how they were used in every situation. The class is not ready to be replaced yet. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the constructors private and you'll get an error message for every attempt to create the object.

Make a private new() operator to do the same trick with heap allocations.

**Edit:** watch out for the code INSIDE the class implementation (including static methods) creating instances of itself. Calling a private constructor from such context is valid and won't trigger an error. Also watch out for friend classes/functions.

Comment: AHA! this sounds promising! Can anyone else confirm that this will catch all the instances?

Comment: Actually, if you make all the constructors private (including the 3 builtin ones) then this should be perfect, as long as there's no friend functions that create new instances.  You don't actually need to make `new` private, that doesn't actually help anything.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I think the advice about `new()` is a garbled version of the idea of using access control of `operator new` and `operator new[]` to selectively prevent dynamic allocation. In the same vein, restricted access to the destructor can be used to selectively prevent non-dynamic allocation. Restricting access to constructors covers both cases, without any power to discriminate between them.

Comment: @everyone excellent, and now that you explained it that way, it makes a lot of sense, Cheers. I think this is exactly the way to go for me, thanks a lot you three!

Answer (score 2):

One guaranteed way to ensure you eliminate all usage of a class is to simply remove the definition of a class or make some key part of it invalid. Then when you compile the project you will get an error for each and every situation that class is used in. When everything is successfully compiled you will know everything has been replaced.

You can of course speed things up a little bit by using find/replace for the simple cases and then manually fix up any remaining cases.

Comment: +1 for a reasonable answer (even if it's just trivial common sense).